# Return value of (std::cin >> variable)

Tags: c++

I am a C++ beginner,

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char v1;
    // valid no warning
    std::cout << (std::cin >> v1) << std::endl; // return value of the expression expected 
    return 0;
}
// output: 1
// return value of the expression is 1?
```

Is the return value of (std::cin >> v1) really 1? Why?

Comment: It depends on how you overload it for you class.

Comment: I am curious what compiler you used to make this work. Turn up your warning levels to catch these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a current compiler that will accept your code as it stands right now. g++, clang and Microsoft all reject it, saying they can't find an overload to match the arguments (i.e., an `operator<<` for `ostream` that takes an `istream` as an operand).

It's possible to get the result you've posited with code on this order: `std::cout << !!(std::cin >> v1) << "\n";`. Depending on the age of the compiler and standard with which it complies, this does one of two things.

With a reasonably current compiler, this will use the Boolean conversion on the istream to get it to match the `!` operator, then apply that (twice) to the result, so you write out the result of that operator.

With old enough compilers, there won't be a Boolean conversion operator, but there will be an overload of `operator!`, which also does a conversion to Boolean (but negated in sense, of course). The result of that will then be negated by the second `!`.

Either way, you end up writing out a Boolean value (or `int` containing zero or one on an old enough compiler) that indicates whether the stream is in a failed or successful state.

This is done to allow you to check input as you're reading it, so you can process input data sanely. For example, when/if you want to read all the values in a file, stopping at the end of the file, or when you encounter something that can't be interpreted as the desired type, you can write code on this general order:

```cpp
// read integers from a file and print out their sum
int temp;
int total = 0;

while (std::cin >> temp) {
    total += temp;
}

std::cout << total << "\n";
```

The `while` loop uses the conversion to Boolean to determine whether an attempt at reading a value was successful or not, so it continues reading values as long as that happens successfully, and quits immediately when reading is unsuccessful.

One common source of errors is to write a loop on this order instead:

```cpp
while (std::cin.good()) { // or almost equivalently, check for end of file.
    std::cin >> temp;
    total += temp;
}
```

But loops like this get the sequence incorrect. One common symptom of the problem with this is that the last number in the file will be added to the total twice instead of once.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin >> v1` returns `cin`; Not sure what type it gets converted to for `std::cout`, but most likely it indicates the state of `cin`, where `1` is `good`

Answer (score 0):

> Is the return value of (std::cin >> v1) really 1

No, see the ref for [cin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/iostream?view=msvc-170#cin), it will return a `istream`.

Your codes will not work, we can not pass `::istream` (std::cin) to operator<< of a `std::ostream` (std::cout).

Shoule be like the following:

```
char v1;
cout << "Input a char:";
cin >> v1;
```

Comment: ... `cout << v1 << endl;`

Answer (score 0):

The program only [works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Nh5q571yQepLyVSm) for Pre-C++11 because the **conversion to bool** is not **explicit**.

Starting from C++11, the program will [no longer work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OrHlJ9YvyVizJPH0) because the **conversion to bool** is **explicit**.

Note that `std::cin >> v1;` returns `std::cin` and not `1`. But there is no [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for `std::ostream` that takes a `std::cin`.

The reason it works for Pre-C++11 is because in this case the conversion to bool was **not explicit**. But starting from C++11, the conversion to bool was made [explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) and so the code no longer compiles.

For example,

```
bool b = std::cin; //WORKS for Pre-C++11 but FAILS for C++11 & onwards
    
bool b{std::cin};  //OK, WORKS for all versions(Pre-C++11 as well as C++11 & onwards) because in direct initialization we can use explicit conversion
```

Comment: Then it's strange. I am working on clang 13.0.0 but it prints the result without warning:-:

Comment: @luma Are you sure you're using clang 13.0.0?  What command line arguments are you giving it?   https://godbolt.org/z/3affon3bx

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis Did you miss/forgot to use C++03 in your given link? [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/T7nz6q4jv) the program compiles with Clang 13.0.0 with C++03.

Comment: @AnoopRana No, I didn't "forget" c++03.  It is _not_ the default language on clang 13, so you have to opt-in to using it that way, and I was replying to someone who did not specify that they chose it to run that way.  That's why I asked what arguments were given.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis Ok i misunderstood your comment then. Yeah the OP might be using the default language version by not specifying the c++03 argument while compiling the code and hence the error. To make you comment more clear, i think you could've instead provided the link with c++03 argument given and show that it works when we opt-in c++03. Also, since OP is already using(according to his first comment) Clang 13.0.0 then he must be using c++03 option since his code compiles without any warning.